# Catch Asp .Net Identity with .Net core on IIS from regular ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I deployed an ASP.NET Core Web application on IIS, so far everything is ok. I  have another ASP.NET MVC application that is using ASP.NET Identity and  injecting a cookie `AspNet.ApplicationCookie` to the browser and afterwards redirecting me to my .Net Core app.

What I need to do is to get this user that was originally inserted on ASP.NET MVC on my .NET Core application and get asp identity authorized from my previous app, both apps have same domain so I can see the cookie in storage.

Question is: how can I configure the .NET Core app that its could get authenticated by ASP.NET cookie from previous application, also the ASP.NET MVC app is a blackbox for me.

This is what I tried so far:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddIdentityCookies(); 
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Update:

This is what i added to my code, but still doesn't get my previous identity
also i got some unfamilliar execeptions

```
services.AddAuthentication(option=> {
        new CookieAuthenticationOptions { Cookie = {

           Domain = ".dev.*****.ru",
           Path ="/",
           Name= ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie",
            }
        };
    }).AddIdentityCookies(option=>new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Cookie = {
           Domain = ".dev.*****.ru",
           Path ="/",
           Name= ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie",
        }
    });
```

[2019-04-12 11:25:51.903 +03:00 WRN] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository
Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.

[2019-04-12 11:25:51.943 +03:00 WRN] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager
Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.

[2019-04-12 11:25:51.977 +03:00 WRN] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager
No XML encryptor configured. Key "41c89830-2ef1-48f7-afa5-16680973e6f2" may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

Comment: You might find the answer on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2). The important bit is setting `CookieAuthenticationOptions` to have a root path for the cookie so that it is accessible to both applications within the domain.

Comment: Hi,i got some edit

Comment: Its run on same IIS, on same machine, different app pools, its have some work around?

Comment: These are warnings that could possibly be ignored. However, I assumed that both applications were running on the same server and therefore had their cookies encrypted with the same machine key. But if they are not, you will have to adopt what @Dimitar is recommending above.

Comment: Our comments crossed. So they are both on the same server, but do they have the same cookie implementation? I also just noticed that you say that the ASP.NET MVC application is a "black box for you"; in this case, you have no knowledge of the type of authentication they are using and how they are storing the authenticated user in the cookie. Therefore, it will be tricky to get them to share the same authentication token.